# Is it possible to force truncation when instantiating Boost cpp_dec_float from a floating point value?

Tags: c++, boost, floating-point, fixed-point, boost-multiprecision

We are writing software doing arithmetic operations on number with 8 fixed decimal digits (8 decimal digits after the `.`).

We have been bitten by the limited precision of built-in floating point types such a `double` a few times, mainly on equality comparisons (which are failing around the 17th decimal). So we tried moving to some **fixed-precision** decimal type.

From its documentation, [`cpp_dec_float`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/floats/cpp_dec_float.html) should be such a type.
So we replaced our `using Decimal = double` with `using Decimal = boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::cpp_dec_float<8>>;`

Everything works mostly fine if we instantiate `Decimal` from strings, but there is a complication when it is instantiated from a floating-point literal:

```
assert(Decimal{0.001} == Decimal{"0.001"});
```

Above assertion fails, since the left-hand-side Decimal instance seems to carry the inexact representation of the literal used to initialize it, **even though this epsilon goes far beyond the requested precision of 8**.

Is there a way to get a "truncate on instatiation" behaviour, so the above assertion is satisfied?
(Ideally, the solution would not require touching all the call sites where such instantiation takes place)

Comment: Not sure what's going wrong here. I'd expect the floating-point value to truncate to 0.001. But it's [generally unreliable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) to initialise this type with floating-point fractionals. You can avoid floating-point by dividing, e.g. `Decimal{1}/1000` or using a UDL such as CNL's `""_cnl` ([example](https://godbolt.org/z/YroYoscYT)).

Comment: Thank you for this comment. I also expected `cpp_dec_float` to truncate to the requested precision, but it is observably not the case. (I don't see any reference to `cpp_dec_float` in the link you provided). Actually, an easy way to avoid the floating point is to initialize from string, such as `Decimal{"0.001"}`, yet I was hoping for a *drop-in* solution, not requiring to touch existing call sites already initializing `Decimal` from `double` variables and literals.

Comment: It is inexact:  print("%1000.1000f\n") % (0.001) ==> 0.001000000000000000020816681711721685132943093776702880859375000...

Comment: @Andrew Could you please elaborate on what is inexact, and what your code statement illustrates?

Comment: @Ad N : An inexact float is one that cannot be accurately represented as a floating point.  An accurate 0.001 would be 0.00100000000000000000000000000000000000000000....  But it cannot be stored that way as a float, as illustrated by this code statement which forces the print to show more accuracy: "print("%100.100f\n") % (0.00100000000000000000000000000000000000000000)".  That statement returns: "0.0010000000000000000208166817117216851329430937767028808593750000000000000000000000000000000000000000", which is not exactly 0.001.

Comment: @Andrew Yes, the question is asked exactly in this context: how to truncate a floating point (approximate) value to the exact precision requested for a `boost::multiprecision` type. I.e. getting the same result than when instantiating it from a `string`. (The question is not about getting exact representation with built-in floating point types.)

Answer (score 0):

This might explain it:

```
0.001 as a 32 bit float is exactly:
0.0009999999310821295
    12345678 are the 8 digits of accuracy
0.0009999999 is 0.001 as a 32 bit float rounded to the 8 digits of accuracy
0.0010000000 is 0.001 truely ecarately 

VS 7 bits of accuracy:
0.0009999999310821295
    1234567
0.001000000
0.001000000
```